# In Silverlight 5, how to get Directory name of a file without Running application Out Of Browser?

Tags: silverlight

In Silverlight 5, I am performing File operations using Open File Dialog. I want to read the Directory Name of the selected file from the Open File Dialog box. But I am getting error "File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied." How to solve this issue ?
It is working fine when I opt for "Running application Out Of Browser with elevated trust". But I don't want to run my app outside of the browser. So my problem is to get the Directory name of the selected file without making application to run out of browser. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You could try to run [Silverlight 5 in the browser with elevated trust](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

This is no guarantee that it will work because the Silverlight app will still be subject to the restrictions imposed by the security settings of the browser.

Comment: Do client machine require these certificates ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it would be a security breach