# Silverlight :Downloading files to a physical location - Access to path denied while Creating a file in a directory

Tags: c#, silverlight, file-io

I tried to write a file to my phisical locations D:\Nithesh . So wrote the code like below :

```
    File.Create(filePath);
    Stream outputStream = File.Open(filePath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

But I was getting  exception saying "Access to path is denied".

I did try isolated storage . But that really didn't suit my requirements. How else can I code this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a  [trusted application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to use [File.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), if your application is not trusted, you have to use a [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

**Note :** For security purposes Silverlight save file dialog must be user-initiated (on a button callback click).
So : on click [Download] show the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), keep a ref on the stream that the user select, download the file, write the download output on the stream (You have to catch UnauthorizedAccessException, DirectoryNotFoundException IOException).

Comment: My client directly wants to save file to a particular location without a dailg box .How Can I make my application trusted through code itself  without manually registry entries ?

Comment: Is your application runing out-of-browser ? It is mandatory for elevated trust. After you can read [this 'how to'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee721082(v=vs.95).aspx). Note that before SL5, you dont have a full access, more infos, [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#file_system_access)

Comment: System administrators can [enable trusted applications to run inside the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537467/in-silverlight-5-how-to-get-directory-name-of-a-file-without-running-applicatio) but it's not user friendly ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in-browser application you should follow the instructions as specified [here at MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) After when you make your application trusted, you can access file system. Again, refer [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721082%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for example.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow as they are subject to 'link rot'. Please edit your answer to include the necessary info to answer the question asked. You should leave the links in as an attribution though and a way for the OP to do some further reading.

Answer (score 0):

My app was working perfectly on localhost, in order to make it run when hosted in the production server I had to sign my .xap file, put the certificate to "trusted publishers" and "trusted root authorities" of the client and modify the registry as described [here](http://www.mistergoodcat.com/post/Silverlight-5-Tidbits-Trusted-applications)